# Justice and general intelligence systems?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, causation, justice

In a world of general intelligence systems. If an AI causes an accident how is justice served? This maybe due to the overlook of a human who is no longer there. And the reason for that would be it was not required at the time. I mean it can't even differentiate between causation and correlation? (Or maybe some research is required to find the causal chain). How is justice served in such a situation?

Comment: Self driving car liability-> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-driving_car_liability

Comment: Couldn't we have one AI that measures the safety standard if the other driving car? (I think this is a bad idea)? but how would u argue against it?

Comment: Not a philosophical but a legal subject, this already occurs, while courts still don't agree. Google for "responsibility tesla accident".

Answer (score 1):

> In a real incident a pedestrian was struck and killed by a
> self-driving car. In this case, the automated car was
> capable of detecting cars and certain obstacles in order to
> autonomously navigate the roadway, but it could not anticipate a
> pedestrian in the middle of the road. This raised the question of
> whether the driver, pedestrian, the car company, or the government
> should be held responsible for her death.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics_of_artificial_intelligence

Later, on trial, prosecutors ruled that the "car"/company was not criminally responsible for the crash. The back-up driver of the vehicle was charged with negligent homicide.

From this incident it seems that causation and correlation (related to the AI system) are not taken into account from the justice system, and it is the driver who at the end holds the responsibility of the outcome.

Currently, self-driving cars are considered semi-autonomous, requiring the driver to pay attention and be prepared to take control if necessary.

I beleive that deviating from this perspective could lead to a dystopian society. If we are to "investigate" causation inside an AI system, besides the "interfaces" between hardware we would also have to analyse the semantics of software too, and subsequently every line of code.

---

**Addition**

I would like to add - in order to grasp the complexity of AI in cars -  that a car autopilot software today has about 100 million lines of code.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149606/discussion-on-answer-by-ioannis-paizis-justice-and-general-intelligence-systems); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the specifics and those aren't really real yet and not specified in the question.

As of right now you'd look at all the humans involved in the process and if they could have prevented the harm. Though that is within reasonable limits, like you can prevent a car accident by not driving a car, but people aren't banning cars because at least some think that the benefits of it outweigh the risk, so in effect it's not seen as criminal negligence or calculated malice to drive a car, but instead an accident is classified as just that "an accident" and unpreventable harm without culprit.

So the possible culprits would not be the AI (as of right now) but the driver and the "provider" (manufacturer, seller, technical inspection etc.). And if it can be found that they acted in criminal intent or preventable negligence then they'll be made the culprit and forced to compensate for that. When it's ruled an accident it's a matter of bad luck and/or insurances.

Now if the AI gets really good to the point where you force trolley problems upon it (force it to make a decision between the life of the driver or an opposing traffic participant, where it's basically no win), that would become a political question as to where society draws has it's preferences. And if society makes such a risk evaluation they would also be responsible to cope with the effects of that.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper: what if the company provides little to no budget to "an accident prevention team." Are there laws around this?

Comment: Sample law: give 10 percent of your profits to this team?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Depending on the industry there might already be safety requirement before a product can enter the market and even afterwards there are usually laws against unsafe or faulty products and the failure to disclose risks and shortcomings. Eventually that comes down to who's got the better lawyers and political capital manufacturers or consumers /consumer protection collectives.

Comment: It's not about the money that they get but whether they can show that it's safe. If they are underfunded that makes it more obvious that it wasn't just an accident but possibly criminal negligence.

Comment: But this would require an ethos of say 15% profit should go to the safety department. But then the definition of safety will be gamed, etc etc